# Wi-Fi search does not occur Debian 11

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware, realtek

I'm new to working with Linux, before that I had onу Linux Mint.

I installed Debian 11 from a bootable USB stick. I tried to install from the netinst version of iso, but I could not connect to the hidden network, so I installed the main system without a graphical shell.

After that, I decided to install from the image of the base system (4.7GB) with the GNOME shell. The installer required an ap for the network card, I added this file to iso and booted the system without access to the Internet.

I expected to be able to connect to the hidden network without problems, but in the system settings under Wi-Fi there was an inscription "Missing firmware".

- My network card is Realtek.
- And USB Wi-Fi Modem.

I downloaded a lot of non-free deb packages to a USB flash drive - realtek-firmware, Linux-firmware-non-free, but nothing changed.

I noticed that when the system starts, when the components are loaded, the last gray inscription says the absence of `rt28070.bin`. I found it and uploaded it to the `/etc/firmware` folder.

After that, the inscription "Missing firmware" disappeared. But no network was detected, it also did not work to connect directly.

Please tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found. I needed to delete `rt2870.bin`, and put the package `firmware-misc-nonfree`!